# Why do all my particles share the same rotation and color? (GLSL Shaders)

Tags: opengl, geometry, shader, particles

Like the title suggests, I am building a particle system in OpenGL using a geometry shader to create billboards from points. Everything seems okay but it looks like all particles share the rotation and color of the first particle. I've checked the inputs of course.
Here are my current vertex and geometry shaders:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location=0) in vec4 in_position;
layout(location=2) in float in_angle;
layout(location=3) in vec4 in_color;

uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;

out VertexData
{
    vec4 color;
    float angle;
} vertex;

void main()
{
    vertex.color = in_color;
    vertex.angle = in_angle;
    gl_Position = in_position;
}
```

Geometry shader:

```
#version 330

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;

uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;

in VertexData
{
    vec4 color;
    float angle;
} vertex[];

out vec4 fragColor;
out vec2 texcoord;

mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle)
{
    axis = normalize(axis);
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    float oc = 1.0 - c;
    return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c, oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s, oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s, 0.0,
    oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s, oc * axis.y * axis.y + c, oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s, 0.0,
    oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s, oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s, oc * axis.z * axis.z + c, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
} // http://www.neilmendoza.com/glsl-rotation-about-an-arbitrary-axis/

    void main()
{
    mat4 R = rotationMatrix( vec3(0,0,1), vertex[0].angle );
    vec4 pos = V * vec4( gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz, 1.0 );
    float size = gl_in[0].gl_Position.w;

    texcoord = vec2( 0.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position = P * ( pos + vec4( texcoord, 0, 0 ) * R * size );
    fragColor = vertex[0].color;
    EmitVertex();

    texcoord = vec2( 1.0, 0.0);
    gl_Position = P * ( pos + vec4( texcoord, 0, 0 ) * R * size );
    fragColor = vertex[0].color;
    EmitVertex();

    texcoord = vec2( 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = P * ( pos + vec4( texcoord, 0, 0 ) * R * size );
    fragColor = vertex[0].color;
    EmitVertex();

    texcoord = vec2( 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position = P * ( pos + vec4( texcoord, 0, 0 ) * R * size );
    fragColor = vertex[0].color;
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in here?

Comment: When you say you have checked the input, how have you done this? Have you tried trying point primitives without a geometry shader? This could be something as simple as the wrong stride/size of your vertex buffer leading to undefined results for each additional vertex.

Comment: I meant that I checked the values in the arrays that I pass to the gpu. Per your suggestion, I have just tried taking out the geometry shader and drawing them as point primitives, same the problem is still there. Thanks for that suggestion, I'll have to look into the buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh I found out what was causing my problem.
I still had two calls to `glVertexAttribDivisor()`, from when I was still using `glDrawArraysInstanced()`.